# onde uso o left join nesse caso? no msql

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysqli, sql-select

Preciso colocar o `left join` nesse caso aqui podem me dizer onde esta o erro?

```
select a.nome_artista, count(*) as numero_musicas 
  from artista a, musica m 
 where m.id_artista = a.id_artista
 group by a.nome_artista
```

Comment: `count(*)` está contando o que? coloque o campo, não pode contar `*` porque tem mais de uma tabela ai

Comment: Ricardo, valeu eu consegui aqui o que eu precisava

Answer (score -3):

Diego, entendendo que tu precisa realizar um left join entre Artista A e Musica M (o que faz sentido pra mim do ponto de vista dos conjuntos):

```
select a.nome_artista, count(*) as numero_musicas 
  from artista a left join musica m on m.id_artista = a.id_artista
 group by a.nome_artista
```

Comment: Não entendi porque foi votado pra baixo. O rapaz precisa dos dados dos artistas com as músicas. O left join precisa ser feito entre as duas tabelas pois eventualmente um artista pode não possuir nenhuma música cadastrada.

Comment: eu consegui aqui o que eu precisava, brigado

Comment: o que eu to vendo aqui agora, é puxar as informações da data da musica mais recente

Comment: @diegoAlves, marca como resolvido caso a tua dúvida tenha resolvido?

Comment: @DiegoAlves, consegue explicar melhor essa questão da música mais recente? Tu queres que a consulta retorne os dados do artista e uma coluna com a data da música mais recente? Ou os dados do  artista + os dados da música mais recente?

Comment: Então, as musicas possuem as datas, eu preciso trazer a informação das musicas mais antigas e as mais novas. eu tentei usar o max e o min mas traz informação com o nome de um artista só com todas as datas sendo que são 3 artistas com nomes diferentes

Comment: Certo, você quer listar as músicas, com seus respectivos artistas e ordenado pela data de inclusão da música?